# Is it possible to connect to FCM backend without SDK

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, desktop-application

This is a general question not bound to any platform,
From what I understand FCM backend servers pushes notifications to the devices that connect to it.

The devices connect through the sdk
So android devices registers a worker to listen for notifications

Can we simulate the same without using the sdk

If it is possible then we can connect to FCM through windows or linux, or even through mac without relying on APNS

Comment: The push notification server (FCM) requires a registered account/project. And there is documentation for [sending from a server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) where the server could be a PC.

Comment: thank you @MorrisonChang, but I am talking about receiving not sending, receiving push notifications on the client's device.

from the resource you provided, I specifically want to connect on the first component which is  the FCM backend

Comment: I would look at the [Javascript client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) as third-party client packages in different programming languages would support similar as no Android or iOS dependencies would be required. Just be aware that FCM backend may do things to make sure apps comply with their Terms Of Service.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, This is definitely very interesting, I am assuming we could register a node service on the user's device that makes this connection and starts listening to notifications. or is it only for browsers?